Rx560x corrupted / not working
I am dualbooting ubuntu and windows 11  on my laptop with ryzen 5 2500u, vega 8 and rx560x. Although I've been on ubuntu for like a month now. I recently noticed that my 2nd gpu (Rx560x) wasn't showing up in thr resource monitor again, and in the about section of the settings. I also checked windows too, and it showed in device manager  bit with a ⚠️ icon under it and didn't show in the redeon app.
I tried and used dmesg to frind what was going on  and it returned this
sudo dmesg | grep -i amdgpu
[    5.240438] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    5.240446] [drm] amdgpu version: 6.7.0
[    5.240484] amdgpu: vga_switcheroo: detected switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.VGA_.ATPX handle
[    5.241941] amdgpu: ATPX version 1, functions 0x00000001
[    5.242122] amdgpu: ATPX Hybrid Graphics
[    5.252198] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[    5.252231] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[    5.261063] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0002 -> 0003)
[    5.295867] [drm:amdgpu_get_bios [amdgpu]] *ERROR* failed to evaluate ATRM got AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE
[    5.296370] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from ATRM
[    5.296375] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: SWBRT33170.001
[    5.296685] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature not supported
[   25.310614] [drm:atom_op_jump [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 20secs aborting
[   25.311007] [drm:amdgpu_atom_execute_table_locked [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing D476 (len 282, WS 4, PS 4) @ 0xD56D
[   25.311309] [drm:amdgpu_atom_execute_table_locked [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing B10A (len 275, WS 4, PS 0) @ 0xB1FD
[   25.311630] [drm:amdgpu_atom_execute_table_locked [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing AF84 (len 117, WS 0, PS 8) @ 0xAFCD
[   25.311931] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: gpu post error!
[   25.311935] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[   25.311969] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
[   25.312060] amdgpu: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22
[   25.315422] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
[   25.315431] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-RAVEN-113
[   25.337366] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   25.337373] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature enabled
[   25.337433] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 1024M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F43FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[   25.337438] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
[   25.337732] [drm] amdgpu: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[   25.337736] [drm] amdgpu: 7440M of GTT memory ready.
[   25.338984] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is smu10_smu
[   25.340073] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[   25.361170] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: reserve 0x400000 from 0xf401c00000 for PSP TMR
[   25.548549] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[   25.575431] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[   25.575434] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
[   25.662107] amdgpu: HMM registered 1024MB device memory
[   25.665260] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
[   25.665287] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Total number of KFD nodes to be created: 1
[   25.665507] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
[   25.665711] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x15dd:0x1002]
[   25.665718] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:15dd
[   25.665746] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 11, active_cu_number 8
[   25.665756] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[   25.665763] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_low uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[   25.665768] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_high uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[   25.665774] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[   25.665780] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[   25.665786] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[   25.665791] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[   25.665797] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[   25.665803] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[   25.665809] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[   25.665814] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[   25.665820] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_0.2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[   25.665826] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
[   25.665831] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
[   25.665837] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
[   25.665843] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 8
[   25.665848] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 8
[   25.669678] amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_sclk_od was not implemented.
[   25.669687] amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_mclk_od was not implemented.
[   25.671136] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.57.0 20150101 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 1
[   25.677792] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   25.677804] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[   40.297073] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.1: bound 0000:04:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])

I have no idea how to fix this or what exactly is even wrong. I'd appreciate any help that I can get.
Thank you
